# Права доступа через Samba

Tags: linux, samba, права-доступа

Прошу помочь разобраться. В Samba полностью одинаково сконфигурированы 3 директории:

```
[mnt]
    comment = mnt
    path = /mnt
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes

[tmp]
    comment = tmp
    path = /tmp
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes

[home]
    comment = tmp
    path = /home/maxim
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes
```

Одного и того-же юзера maxim пускает home и temp. Но не пускает в mnt. Проблема очевидно в правах, но не могу понять что сделать. Менял владельца /mnt на maxim. Выдавал директории права 777. Ничего не помогает. Вот текущие права:

```
[maxim-manjaro maxim]# ls -ld /mnt
drwxrwsrwx 3 maxim maxim 4096 мар 20 14:16 /mnt
[maxim-manjaro maxim]# ls -ld /home/maxim
drwx------ 17 maxim maxim 4096 мар  29 15:29 /home/maxim
[maxim-manjaro maxim]# ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 13 root root 400 мар  29 15:30 /tmp
```

Что тут может быть не так?